# How can I have a full report about state of shared folders in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7

I want to know about how many people are in using a file shared on my computer and 
have full report about it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For this purpose, go to **File Server Manager** like as picture one. 
In this section go to Run and type

> fsmgmt.msc

and press enter.
As you can see in picture, all of shared folders and number of clients in **Shares** part are visible.
Also you can see the names of those who are connected to your computer in **Sessions** part and information 
about **Open Files** part.

[image: Picture 1]

As well as you can use

> net share

command in Windows cmd like as picture two.

[image: Picture 2]

Comment: you can also use `net file` to list files from command line

Answer (score 3):

There are two Powershell WMI classes that can be used to obtain this information as well.  The `Win32_Shares` class will show you information about the folders you have shared on your computer, or a remote computer.  It's used like this:

```
Get-WmiObject -class Win32_Shares
```

Or remotely:

```
Get-WmiObject -class Win32_Shares -computerName {SERVERNAME}
```

You can also view very specific connection information with the `Win32_SessionConnection` object.  It will show information about each connection active to shares.  The user, the computer name and the IP address.  It's used like this:

```
Get-WmiObject -class Win32_SessionConnection -computerName {SERVERNAME} | Select Dependent
```

The output of the command is piped through select dependent because it reports more information than you need for the purposes of this question.  As such you can pipe it through `Select-Object` (shortened to select) to grab a specific property from each object returned by the WMI query.

On our production file server, running the query returned 636 active connections.  You can get a count by piping the output of the last command through `Measure-Object`.

```
Get-WmiObject -class Win32_SessionConnection -computerName {SERVERNAME} | Select Dependent | Measure-Object
```

[image]

Hope you find this information useful.

I took this a little further... Here's something you can paste into PowerShell for output that's a little easier to read.  You'll have to run PowerShell with elevated privileges to access the `Win32_SessionConnection` object.  Be sure to change the value of the `$server` variable at the top of the snippet.

```
$server = 'CHANGEME' ## <--CHANGE THIS STRING VALUE

function __construct($proparray) {
    $rtnObj = new-object PSCustomObject;
    $rtnObj | add-member -type noteproperty -name 'ip' -value $proparray[0];
    $rtnObj | add-member -type noteproperty -name 'share' -value $proparray[1];
    $rtnObj | add-member -type noteproperty -name 'user'-value $proparray[2];
    return $rtnObj
}

$cnxArray = @();

gwmi win32_sessionconnection -computer $server|select dependent|% { $cnxArray += __construct([string]$_ -replace '\@\{|\}|\"|[A-Za-z\.]+=|Win32_','').split(",") }

$cnxArray;
## You may have to press enter if this last line does not process with the paste.
```